# Transparency issue in customized bottom navigation view of Shell's Tabbar .Net MAUI Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I have implemented a custom shell renderer for Shell's Tabbar Maui, to customize the bottom navigation view with custom design as below,

**Actual Behavior:** They are coming as white, even we set transparent color to the background of the bottom Navigation view.(refer below screenshot)

[Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kueOk.png)

**Sample :** [https://github.com/dotnet/maui/files/14124584/ShellTabBarSample.zip](https://stackoverflow.com)

Any suggestion on this?

**Expected Behavior:** Region between Fab button (Red) and custom shape bottom navigation view should be transparent. (refer below screenshot)

[Expected design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4bYJ.png)

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/RadekVyM/Navbar-Animation-1

Comment: According to Nikos Basdanis's link, you can refer to the code in TabBarViewDrawable.cs file, the `createPath` method makes the region between circle button and custom custom tabbar view transparent.